# Make Buffer as fast as Files.copy

Tags: java, stream, copy, buffer

I have some Questions about Buffers in java.
1. Why is Files.copy faster then a normal sized buffer with Streams?
2. Is there a way to get buffers so fast like Files.copy OR is there an alternative?
3. If you have an fast alternative how can I modify the bytes (like with buffers)

Comment: 99,9% of people here are because they need help, so that's nothing special. Remember that you're not paying for this service, so there are no guarantees on anything. And if you think that this is frustrating for you, imagine the people who answer the questions. People come here without doing any research and imagine that they have a *right* to get help, or in some cases even full programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Files.copy` is faster because it uses native code to perform the copy, ensuring that the fastest possible way for that platform is used. When using regular streams most of the code is non-native (except for the FileStreams), so it can't take advantage of any possible performance benefits of the platform.

If you want to modify the bytes while they're in transit, your best bet would be to go with [FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) and work with `ByteBuffers`.

Comment: as far as i know, in jdk-9 `Files.lines` is operating upon memory mapped files, which would make them really fast.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, but that would affect text file processing only.